# Mic works fine on windows but not on mac?

Tags: microphone

I have a cheap amazon microphone since my headphones don't have one. It works perfectly fine, on any windows device. No matter what, I have issues with it on my macbook air laptop. Specifically, I plug it in to my computer, and it starts working just fine. Soon enough (after a few seconds), it begins to become (what I can only describe as) very robotic and glitchy. After leaving it on for a while, it works fine but has a delay of about 1.5 seconds, which makes videos and calls extremely awkward. Does anybody have a fix to this?

Comment: Is the 3.5mm plug [3-pole](https://static.bhphoto.com/images/images500x500/1393517540_1033746.jpg) or or [4-pole](https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/71qsyara7KL._AC_SL1500_.jpg)?

Comment: It's a 3.5 mm with a usb adapter

Comment: Sorry its a 3-pole